# Получение точки пересечения окружностей на python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, уравнения

```py
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Eq, solve

n = input().split()


xs = [n[0], n[3], n[6]]
ys = [n[1], n[4], n[7]]
ps = [n[2], n[5], n[8]]
ds = []


def dist(p):
    return -abs(p)**3 * 1.1 * 10**-5 + p**2 * 0.0096 - p * 2.85 + 199.19

def kryg(x, y):
    pass



for i in range(3):
    ds.append(dist(int(ps[i])))
    # print(dist(int(ps[i])))
    # print(int(ps[i]))

# print(xs)
# print(ys)
# print(ps)
# print(ds)

# задаем символьные переменные
x, y = Symbol('x'), Symbol('y')

# уравнения окружностей
eq1 = Eq((x - int(xs[0]))**2 + (y - int(ys[0]))**2, int(ds[0])**2)
eq2 = Eq((x - int(xs[1]))**2 + (y - int(ys[1]))**2, int(ds[1])**2)
eq3 = Eq((x - int(xs[2]))**2 + (y - int(ys[2]))**2, int(ds[2])**2)

# решение уравнений
solution = solve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (x, y))

# извлекаем координаты точек пересечения окружностей
intersection_points = [(float(sol[0]), float(sol[1])) for sol in solution]

# выводим результат
for point in intersection_points:
    print(f"Точка пересечения: ({point[0]}, {point[1]})")
```

Код должен выводить 011.95 055.88, когда я ввожу 085 072 050 197 116 001 127 095 029,
но выводит только пустой список. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149494/discussion-on-question-by-vov7a------pytho); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.